# How to generate xpath by looking for a string in an HTML document?

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I have an HTML document, and I am willing to find out the xpath to an element containing a certain string.

To elaborate a bit more:

My HTML document is created dynamically and I have no specific names for s. The divs I am interested at look like (more or less):

```
<div>Country: China</div>
<div>Type: Earphones</div>
```

I want to get the whole string "Country: China". In order to do so, I want to find the xpath to this div by searching for "Country:" in the HTML.

I hope I was specific enough... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ways:

```
//div[contains(child::text(), "Country:")]
//div/child::text()[contains(., "Country:")]/parent::node()
```

If you want to try things out within a browser, try out [in-browser XPath bookmarklet](http://smallfixes.blogspot.com/2011/01/xpath-tester-bookmarklet.html).